# Smokes blue sometimes

Tags: diesel, hyundai, smoke

Car starts immediately smoking blue out of exhaust 
approximately one time in a month. Smokes hard. I see it 
from mirror. Only way to stop it is to shut down engine and 
start again 1-2 minutes after. Everything will be normal. 
Hyundai sonata 2.0 crdi 2006 137 000 km

Answer (score 1):

Oil smoke for several seconds on start is the definition of valve stem seal failures. Also assuming general oil consumption is low . When the engine is off ,a little oil seeps down the valve stems , when started any leaked oil burns off at one time . While running this oil seepage is so small that you do not notice it. I had a Chevy Vortec V-6 that did it, I bought the seals ( cheap rubber "O" rings) but decided it was too much work to put them in . So I just put in a quart of oil about every 3000 miles.

Answer (score 0):

You're burning oil.  The amount of smoke you see is irrelevant as it could be affected by how long it was parked.  I suspect you are leaking oil along a valve but it could be a few different things such as a stuck piston ring.

Comment: Could you add any suggestions you have for diagnosing or solving an issue like this?

Comment: oil levels remains constant long period of time, it isnt burning oil constantly. it only happened when i am driving with constant speed. and restarting the engine solves problem. i know from color it is oil. but how it starts immediately and stops. even on parking at the full throttle there is no smoke

Comment: you just told me "it's obviously oil but it's not burning oil".  If it's obviously oil, it's oil.  It takes an incredibly small amount of oil to make your tail pipe smoke.  You could be burning less than a quart between oil changes.

Comment: when it starts burning i can see from side mirror, i stop, restart the engine after 2 minutes and everything is fine. and it is not burning oil whole time, even at full throttle there is no any smoke. 2nd problem. im not sure, but i think oil level increases.

Comment: if your oil level is increasing, it could be a broken ring.  You may have to have someone check your oil for contamination.  You could be getting gasoline in it past a broken ring.

Comment: Could it be a self-cleaning diesel particulate filter making the smoke?